# Example of a decreasing sequence of nonempty closed sets in $R^{n}$ with empty intersection

Tags: real-analysis

I found this problem in Wheeden's *Measure and Integral*, but I'm wondering if there is either a typo or if I'm misunderstanding something. The problem is stated as follows:

*Give an example of a decreasing sequence of nonempty closed sets in R$^{n}$
whose intersection is empty.*

But doesn't this violate the completeness of R$^{n}$? The only way I can think to have an empty intersection would be to have open or half-open sets, it seems impossible to have closed sets where the intersection is empty.

Does anyone know if this is a mistake or if I'm not understanding things correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $[n,\infty)$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ah, I was having a bit of a dumb moment and was thinking in terms of intervals, not open and closed sets. Thank you very much, this was the light bulb I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a decresing sequence of disjoint union of nonempty closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^m,\forall m \in \Bbb{N}$ with empty intersection.

You cannot find though a decresing sequence of closed and $\text{bounded}$ sets whose intersection is empty because from $\text{Heine-Borel}$ we have that in $\mathbb{R}^m$ a closed and bounded set is compact.

And a decresing sequence of compact sets $A_n$ in a complete metric space has the property that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \neq \emptyset$ from Cantor's intersection theorem.

But if you take closed unbounded rectangles for instance, then you can find a sequence with such property.

Take in $\mathbb{R}^m$ the sequence $$A_n=[n,+\infty) \times .... \times [n +\infty)$$ ($m-$times the product where, $m$ depends on the dimension)

Or products of intervals of the form $[a_n,+\infty)$ where $a_n$ is an increasing sequence of natural numbers